# Xamarin forms with Azure AD B2C getting 401 Unauthorized while calling web api

Tags: api, xamarin, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

[image]i have implemented Azure B2C Attentication in `Xamarin` using `Microsoft.Identity.Client` nuget package.
after successful login it returning me a Id_Token and if I use this Id token to fetch the web api then the unAuthorid 401 error.Im using this scope

```
https://{TenatName}.onmicrosoft.com/api/Read.All
```

Comment: You should use access token instead of id token.

Comment: Still getting unthorized

Comment: Parse your access token and provide screenshots.

Comment: Now Check i have edited

Comment: Is this the client id of your api application? https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivtEd.png

Comment: no its not client id of api .its client id of Client mobile app registration

Comment: we are facing issue how we can get api client id in this token in aud

Comment: How do you set up the `scope`?

Comment: `scope`: `{api app client id}/{scope name}`.

Comment: https://{Tenat}.onmicrosoft.com/{Client Id of client app for mobile}/algo.read

Comment: im adding scope like this https://{Tenat}.onmicrosoft.com/{Client Id of client app for mobile}/algo.read

Comment: where from get the scope from api app or client mobile app

Comment: You should put in the client id of the **api application**.

Comment: and scope name also from the api app?

Comment: of course！！！！！！

Comment: It is the `scope name` of the `api application` you exposed.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbdfB.png

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIxz4.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234185/discussion-between-zubairz-and-carl-zhao).

Answer (score 1):

You need to create two applications in the Azure AD B2C portal, one representing the **client application** and the other representing the **api application**, then use the user to log in to the client application, and use the client application to access the api application.

First, you need to **expose** the api of the api application:
[image]

Next, go to the client application, add the scope exposed by the api application to the client application (you can find your exposed api permissions in **My APIs**), so that the client can access the api, and then grant the **admin consent** for the permission.

[image]

Finally, I use the [ROPC user flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-ropc-policy?tabs=app-reg-ga&pivots=b2c-user-flow) to obtain the token.

[image]

Parse the token：

[image]

Comment: Can i get token with the get call like when i login with azure portal and after login it will return in  my app with token .so then we can use this token

Comment: @zubairz  If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you. :)